# JQuery: Selector only selects first class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select classes that can appear multiple times, but JQuery only selects the first instance.

JQuery

```
$(function(){
$(".openNews").click(function() {
    alert("click");

    $(this).parent().find('.newsContent').toggleClass("newsContent-expand");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("newsItem-expand");
});
});
```

HTML (there can be many of these newsItem divs, all wrapped in one main container)

```
<div class="newsItem">
     <div class="openNews">G</div>
     <div class="newsHeadline">
          <span class="headline">The other thing</span>
          <span class="author">by: author</span>
          <span class="time">12/07/2012 @ 12:57 pm</span>
     </div>
     <div class="newsContent">
        sdf<br>
        sdf<br>
        sdf<br>
        sdfdsfsdfsdfsd<br>
        sdfsdf sdf                   
     </div>
</div>
```

The alert is there just for troubleshooting.

Clicking the 'G' should trigger the transition, but this only works for the first newsItem. All subsequent newsItems do nothing when clicking on 'G', unless the item above it has already transitioned.

I can get it to work just fine if I watch for a click on newsHeadline instead, but that leads to issues where clicking on a newsHeadline causes one above it to transition instead, or you have to hunt around for the clickable part (wouldn't see a click on the headline text, for instance).

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gWufx/2/  .. Can you provide the `HTML and CSS` for the other elements that does not seem to work as well ??

Comment: Also the code that you have written will only trigger the transitions in the current `newsItem `you have clicked

Answer (score 0):

In order to select every instance of a class, don't use find, just keep it simple:

```
$('.newsContent').[do something here, toggle, etc]
```